# Issue with asynchronous call in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, asynchronous

In my angular app, in the below scenario, I'm facing an issue.

There are three files

**mainCtrl.js**

On application load, the `init()` mainCtl.js will be triggered which will call the flowService like this

```
flowService.configureSteps();
```

Which will call the flowService and make a server call to get the data.

**flowService.js**

```
function configureSteps() {
    salesService.getSalesOrder().then(function(response) {
            salesService.setSalesOrder(response);
    });
}
```

This will save the `salesOrder` to the service which is to be retrieved in the `subCntrl`

**subCtrl.js**

In the init of the subCntrl I'm trying to get the salesOrder which I have saved in the service.

```
function init() {
   salesService.getSalesOrder();
}
```

**Issue**

When I hit the url like this

```
http://www.myapp.com/review#/subpage
```

1. It will make hit the mainCtrl
2. From there it will call the service and make the server call
3. As it is asynchronous, it will be redirected to subCntrl
4. It will try to retrieve the salesOrder which is not yet received from the server.

How can this be made synchronous. ?

Comment: You could have `getSalesOrder` return a Promise that resolves once (or if) `setSalesOrder` is called. You don't `make it synchronous` - you *change your code* to handle the asynchronicity.

Comment: `How can this be made synchronous?` It can't. And if it could, it shouldn't. You're thinking backwards. Instead of trying to bend things your way, learn how to deal with asynchronism and embrace its power.

Comment: @JeremyThille Can you please suggest in which way this scenario can be handled.  ?

Comment: @CertainPerformance You mean by using $q service ?

Comment: How is `subCntrl` getting called in the flow  ? There can be 1 approach that surely will work but I need to understand the flow

Comment: @ShashankVivek There is a file for setting the routing rules which I haven't mentioned here. So if there is #/subpage in the url, the subCntrl will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Use events to let the `subCtrl.js` know that the value has been received. Now, since its still operating under `$digest` cycle, so you can easily handle the UI of `subCtrl.js`. Inject `$rootScope` in both controller and service.

**flowService.js**

```
function configureSteps() {
    salesService.getSalesOrder().then(function(response) {
            salesService.setSalesOrder(response);
            $rootScope.$emit('order-recieved');
    });
}
```

**subCtrl.js**

```
function init() {
   $rootScope.$on('order-recieved',function(){
      salesService.getSalesOrder();
   })
}
```

Comment: Yea I have already tried this. This will work. But I have another scenario where there wont be #/subpage in the  url. In that case I'm manually redirecting to subPage. In that case the $rootScope.$on will not be available as the subPage.js is not rendered in the browser.

Comment: @I'mnidhin Can you create a small plunkr to replicate your scenario. It'll help me to understand it better and provide suggestions with a working code.

Comment: ok.. Can we return a promise and make use of it in the controller ?

Answer (score 0):

You can move your **mainCtrl.js** `flowService.configureSteps()` call into:

1. the **resolve** state function ([UI-Router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/))
2. **$routeChangeStart** event callback ([NgRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute))

With UI-Router state you can set a resolve function that will be executed **before** accessing the referred state, making possible to do *syncronous* stuff before the instantiation of that state's controller.

In your case you can do your `flowService.configureSteps()` before accessing the **mainCtrl** and do the `salesService.getSalesOrder()` before accessing the **subCtrl** (but surely after the previous order save).

---

With ngRoute you can define a *routeChange callback* as:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, currentRoute, previousRoute) {
    //
});
```

in this callback you can do your logic **before** route activation, being sure that you will have what you need when you hit your page.

---

Share your route/state configuration if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented using promise.

**flowService.js**

```
 function configureSteps() {
        var salesPromise = salesService.getSalesOrder().then(function(response) {
                salesService.setSalesOrder(response);
        });
        return salesPromise ;
    }

salesService.setPromise(configureSteps()); // Saves the promise to a service
```

**subCtrl.js**

```
function init() {
 salesService.getPromise().then(function() {
       salesService.getSalesOrder(); // This will be called only on resolve of the promise.
    });

}
```

Write the `setPromise` and `getPromise` in the service.